# reading xml using php to replace in between tags

Tags: php, xml

Hi I want to know how to how to do this using php properly.

1. Load XML document
2. Find and Replace Text
3. Save the xml in new name

XML Data is here cant post here due to unknown reason.
http://pastebin.com/A3rDtwzp

I want to find the text in between content tags and replace it with current year for all the all the tags in xml.

Also if can please guide me easy method thanks.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Load XML document

```
 <?php
    // Issues an E_STRICT error
    $doc = DOMDocument::loadXML('<root><node/></root>');
    echo $doc->saveXML();
    ?>
```

Find and Replace Text

```
<?php 

// The text string 
$text = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog."; 

// The word we want to replace 
$oldWord = "brown"; 

// The new word we want in place of the old one 
$newWord = "blue"; 

// Run through the text and replaces all occurrences of $oldText 
$text = str_replace($oldWord , $newWord , $text); 

// Display the new text 
echo $text; 

?>
```

answer of 3

```
<?php
    $docfile = new DOMDocument( );
    $eleT = $docfile->createElement( 'Root' );
    $eleT->nodeValue = 'Hello XML World';
    $docfile->appendChild( $eleT );
    $docfile->save('MyXmlFile.xml');
?>
```

Comment: i want all of them to work together :P like open xml  (http://pastebin.com/A3rDtwzp) find and replace text and save it thnx :)